# Why is a circle with a cut not a Lipschitz domain?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

I know the zero-centered circle with Radius $R$ and with a cut $\Omega = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | |x| < R, x \neq \lambda e_1 \textrm{ for } 0 \leq \lambda < R\}$ is not a Lipschitz domain.

The reason that was given to me is, that $\Omega$ does not lie to one side of $\partial \Omega$. However I don't really see how that implies that the domain is non-Lipschitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near any point $x_0=\lambda e_1$ with $0\le \lambda<R$, you cannot find a neighbourhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that $U\cap \Omega$ is  the set of points in $U$ that are "below" (relative to some hyperplane through $x_0$) the graph of a Lipschitz function. This is simply because such a (small) neighbourhood would lack points that are $\notin\Omega$ and "above" the function graph.